# Help to create shadow with mesh tool

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I searched already on internet and my colleagues. Mesh tool is used to create realistic shadow in Illustrator it is mostly found in Freepik vectors. Please help me to re-create this effect your help will be really appreciated. And it will also help me in my career I'm self-taught graphic designer. Here is the reference image: mesh tool used

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can create this type of shadow using blend tool.

for that you need to follow below steps :

1. Take **one rectangle** shape.
2. Take **same rectangle** shape **twice**.you can very color as per your requirement
3. **Select both Rectangle.**
4. Choose Object > Blend > **Blend option.**
5. Make spacing as image show
   **Spacing: specified steps - 4**

[image]

6. Choose Object > Blend > make

[image]

Comment: i know this method but it is not that way see my reference image carefully. i was searching whole day about this and i feel it may some sort of plugin is used to create such effect. what you think please let me know anyway thanks for your answer

Comment: Thank you for guiding me :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on the type of shadow that you want to make for longer shadow you maybe could use blend tool but for "basic" shadow you can use "Effect>Stylize>Drop Shadow" OR "Effect>Stylize>Outer Glow"

Answer (score 0):

Thats a complex way to insert shadows but it goes like this:
take 2 Rectangles and select 1 of them
go to objects> Create gradient mesh and make sure that the mesh is white
now select the mesh you just created and go to  appearance and then select opacity
and set it to multiply
now select mesh tool on the left panel and set a point where ever you want your shadow
select that dot and change the fill color to black
ta da its done